# Wicket and Wicket-select2 both use PageParameter 'q'. How to solve?

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, jquery-select2

I have a set of `PageParameter`s for my page, one is `q` (for query). This allows for nice URLs like:

http://myapplication/search?q=myquery.

But when I have a `wicket-select2` component on my page, it initializes the query for the select2 with the same value of the `PageParameter` `q`.

This causes the select2 to return an empty list of options, while the user has not even select anything yet.

I know I can change the name of my PageParameters (unfortunately, some clients will have to change urls). Or I can override the methods in `select2` that use the `q` parameters.

I wondered if there is a better solution?

**[Update]**
I also posted this question on the Wicket mailinglist, and was asked to create an issue: https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/issues/563

Will post the answer when thats done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed in this [1] answer you can use stateless mounting for this

In most recent 7.x version (not merged to master yet) you can use following code to change mapping

```
Select2MultiChoice<CategoryTranslation> c = new Select2MultiChoice<CategoryTranslation>("categories");
c.getSettings().setQueryParam("qq");
```

This most probably will be the final solution :)

[1] http://markmail.org/message/ox7rmtzqwfqt5np5

Comment: Thank you Maxim for the very fast solution. This is again a good example of the great wicket community!

Comment: Is wicket-select2 going to support Wicket7? I'm already migrating away from it because of that. Maybe i should stop.

Comment: I guess you are still using `com.vaynberg.wicket.select2:wicket-select2`, Please use `org.wicketstuff:wicketstuff-select2` for wicket 7/8 support